# Reconciling difference in fft output between pytorch 1.5.0 and pytorch 1.9.0

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pytorch, fft

I am attempting to make some python3 code that works with pytorch 1.5.0 also work correctly on newer versions (I am currently using pytorch 1.9.0). More specifically, I am attempting to update the code which does fast fourier transforms. I am trying to replace torch.rfft() in pytorch 1.5.0 with torch.fft.fftn() and torch.view_as_real() in pytorch 1.9.0. I noticed that I am getting a slightly different output when I run the following:

Using PyTorch 1.5.0:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
arr = torch.from_numpy(np.array([[1.,2.,3.,4.,5.],
                                 [6.,7.,8.,9.,10.],
                                 [11.,12.,13.,14.,15.],
                                 [16.,17.,18.,19.,20.]]))
ftt_arr = torch.rfft(arr,2,onesided=False)
print(fft_arr)
```

Using PyTorch 1.9.0:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
arr = torch.from_numpy(np.array([[1.,2.,3.,4.,5.],
                                 [6.,7.,8.,9.,10.],
                                 [11.,12.,13.,14.,15.],
                                 [16.,17.,18.,19.,20.]]))
fft_arr = torch.fft.fftn(arr,norm="backward")
fft_arr = torch.view_as_real(fft_arr)
print(fft_arr)
```

The outputs for the two Fast Fourier Transforms are the following:

pytorch 1.5.0:

```
tensor([[[211.0000,   0.0000],
         [-10.8090,  13.1760],
         [ -9.6910,   4.2003],
         [ -9.6910,  -4.2003],
         [-10.8090, -13.1760]],

        [[-50.0000,  51.0000],
         [  0.5878,  -0.8090],
         [ -0.9511,   0.3090],
         [  0.9511,   0.3090],
         [ -0.5878,  -0.8090]],

        [[-51.0000,   0.0000],
         [  0.8090,   0.5878],
         [ -0.3090,  -0.9511],
         [ -0.3090,   0.9511],
         [  0.8090,  -0.5878]],

        [[-50.0000, -51.0000],
         [ -0.5878,   0.8090],
         [  0.9511,  -0.3090],
         [ -0.9511,  -0.3090],
         [  0.5878,   0.8090]]], dtype=torch.float64)
```

pytorch 1.9.0:

```
tensor([[[ 2.1000e+02,  0.0000e+00],
         [-1.0000e+01,  1.3764e+01],
         [-1.0000e+01,  3.2492e+00],
         [-1.0000e+01, -3.2492e+00],
         [-1.0000e+01, -1.3764e+01]],

        [[-5.0000e+01,  5.0000e+01],
         [ 2.2204e-15,  0.0000e+00],
         [ 1.7764e-15, -4.4409e-16],
         [ 1.7764e-15, -4.4409e-16],
         [ 2.2204e-15,  0.0000e+00]],

        [[-5.0000e+01,  0.0000e+00],
         [-1.7764e-15,  0.0000e+00],
         [-8.8818e-16,  0.0000e+00],
         [-8.8818e-16,  0.0000e+00],
         [-1.7764e-15,  0.0000e+00]],

        [[-5.0000e+01, -5.0000e+01],
         [ 2.2204e-15,  0.0000e+00],
         [ 1.7764e-15,  4.4409e-16],
         [ 1.7764e-15,  4.4409e-16],
         [ 2.2204e-15,  0.0000e+00]]], dtype=torch.float64)
```

All the output values seem to vary by around +/- 1, which I am unable to explain or reconcile.

Comment: Why don't you use torch.fft.rfft in pytorch 1.9? https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.fft.rfft.html#torch.fft.rfft

Comment: The original code uses pytorch 1.5.0 torch.rfft() on a 3D matrix, so I would use torch.fft.rttfn() to do a 3 dimensional fft, but the original code uses torch 1.5.0 torch.rfft() with parameter 'onesided=False' (which means the output is the full complex result, and is not removing redundant results). In Pytorch 1.9.0, torch.fft.rfftn() does not have a 'onesided' parameter to achieve this, so I use torch.fft.fftn() instead.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following helps

```
import torch
a = torch.arange(0,4).view(1,1,2,2).float()
print(a)
```

Now begins code for PyTorch 1.9

```
def dft_amp(img):
    fft_im = torch.view_as_real(torch.fft.rfftn(img, dim=(2,3),norm="backward"))
    #torch.rfft( img, signal_ndim=2, onesided=False )
    print('Pytorch FFT 1.9',fft_im)
    fft_amp = fft_im[:,:,:,:,0]**2 + fft_im[:,:,:,:,1]**2
    return torch.sqrt(fft_amp + 1e-10)

b = dft_amp(a)
print('Pytorch 1.9 amp', b)
```

The output for PyTorch 1.9 is

```
tensor([[[[0., 1.],
          [2., 3.]]]])
Pytorch FFT 1.9 tensor([[[[[ 6.,  0.],
           [-2.,  0.]],

          [[-4.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.]]]]])
Pytorch 1.9 amp tensor([[[[6.0000e+00, 2.0000e+00],
          [4.0000e+00, 1.0000e-05]]]])
```

Now begins code for PyTorch 1.5

```
def dft_amp(img):
    fft_im = torch.rfft( img, signal_ndim=2, onesided=False )#torch.view_as_real(torch.fft.rfftn(a, dim=(2,3),norm="backward"))
    
    print('Pytorch FFT 1.5',fft_im)
    fft_amp = fft_im[:,:,:,:,0]**2 + fft_im[:,:,:,:,1]**2
    return torch.sqrt(fft_amp + 1e-10)

b = dft_amp(a)
print('Pytorch 1.5 amp', b)
```

The output for PyTorch 1.5 version is

```
tensor([[[[0., 1.],
          [2., 3.]]]])
Pytorch FFT 1.5 tensor([[[[[ 6.,  0.],
           [-2.,  0.]],

          [[-4.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.]]]]])
1.5 amp tensor([[[[6.0000e+00, 2.0000e+00],
          [4.0000e+00, 1.0000e-05]]]])
```

Values in both versions match !